# Making a table row a link with specific CSS class

Tags: hyperlink, html-table, row, href

I'm currently using a script for a popup window, where when you hit the link, a nice graphic popup window will appear. My problem is, that in it's current form it's a text link, which are working fine. But I want the entire row, that being the row the link is in, to be pushable, and open the popup window, instead of just the link.

Some will say I should use an onlick command of some sort, but my problem is, that my current link is defined as:

```
<a href="#?w=400" rel="popup1" class="poplight">Link</a>
```

And I have no idea how to add the rel and class to an onclick command for the row fx.
So is there some smart way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

you can use this trick to make a whole cell a link

simply, add the text you want to link it in a `<div>` and set both width and height 100%

HTML:

```
<td><a href="#"><div>link</div></a></td>
```

CSS:

```
td>a>div {width:100%; height:100%}
```

you can see an example at JSfiddle (the second row):
http://jsfiddle.net/w8W4L/